# filter datagridview using another datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I have a text file with size about 10-20 MB.

I want to perfom this options.

1) read the text file and split.

2) move all the data in each line into a datagrid view.

3) create an addition datagridview. that the user can define which line can be visible and which not per a values of 1 column (filter).

I have written a code however however it take a long time.
reading to the first datagrid view the text takes about 40 secound.

when I tried to filter it takes about also 40-50 secound till the user filter it,

is there a way to reduce the time? what is the best way to do this kind of thing? and does using a datasource can be helpful?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use linq.

Read your file like this and you have a list of file lines.

```
var lst = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).ToList();
```

Now you can filter your list by linq statements.

And you can simply show the list in your datagrid.

If you want to show all data in datagrid, it takes time.

You can also create a class for that purpose

```
public class MyLine
{
    public string Line {get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can read the file and have a list or your class, like this:

```
var lst = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("")
                 .Select(x => new MyLine() { Line = x, IsVisible = true });
```

Then for getting visible ones write this query:

```
var Visibles = lst.Where(x => x.IsVisible);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want the user to filter it out how can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain more about your project and text file and the form design? Or send a picture of your form design.